# Display all nodes inside a tagname with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I'm trying to use the loadXMLDoc() JavaScript function to load data from an XML document and show it on my page's DIV when a button is clicked. So far I can't get any content in my DIV, I want to load all elements within an specific tagname.

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Fruits>
  <Cell>Apples</Cell>
  <Cell>Bananas</Cell>
  <Cell>Strawberries</Cell>
</Fruits>
<Vegetables>
  <Cell>Lettuce</Cell>
   <Cell>Tomatoes</Cell>
  <Cell>Carrots</Cell> 
</Vegetables>
```

Here's the JavaScript:

```
function fruits()  
{
    var  
    xmlhttp;  
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)

    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari  
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  
    }  
    else  
    {// code for IE6, IE5  
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
    }  
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  
    {  
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)  
        {  
            xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
            document.getElementById("food").innerHTML=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("fruits"); 
        }  
        xmlhttp.open("GET","document.xml", true);  
        xmlhttp.send();  
    }

    function vegetables()  
    {
        var  
        xmlhttp;  
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)

        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari  
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  
        }  
        else  
        {// code for IE6, IE5  
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
        }  
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  
        {  
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)  
        {  
            xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
            document.getElementById("food").innerHTML=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("vegetables"); 
        }  
        xmlhttp.open("GET","document.xml", true);  
        xmlhttp.send();  
    }
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<button type="button" onclick="fruits()">Fruits</button>
<button type="button" onclick="vegetables()">Vegetables</button>
<div id="food">Please select your favorite</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function `fruits()` is not closed properly, and your function `vegetables()` has ended up inside function `fruits()`,

the same goes for defining the function `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()`

so these functions will not even be available until `fruits()` is called.

Your code should look like this:

```
function fruits()  
    {
        var  
        xmlhttp;  
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)

        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari  
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  
        }  
        else  
        {// code for IE6, IE5  
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
        }  
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)  
            {  
                xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
                document.getElementById("food").innerHTML=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("fruits"); 
            }
        }

        //something went wrong here : this code ended up in the function that was to be called when xmlhttp was done with its GET operation.
        //consequently it was never called
        xmlhttp.open("GET","document.xml", true);  
        xmlhttp.send();  
    } // <-- this here bracket was missing

    function vegetables()  
    {
        var  
        xmlhttp;  
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari  
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  
        }  
        else  
        {
            // code for IE6, IE5  
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  
        {  
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)  
            {  
                xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
                document.getElementById("food").innerHTML=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("vegetables"); 
            }  
        }

        //the same thing happened here

        xmlhttp.open("GET","document.xml", true);  
        xmlhttp.send();  
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Timothy, I'm new in coding, can you please give me an example on how can I fix it please? Much appreciated!

Comment: Hi Ken, and welcome to StackOverflow.
I updated the answer for you, it now contains the code as it probably should be, with some comment annotations on where things went wrong.
To prevent things like this happening in the future, keep close track on your code formatting, indentation is a good tool to prevent this and syntax highlighting editors help a lot too!

If my answer was helpful to you, don't forget to upvote it or if it solved your problem, make sure to mark it as an accepted answer.

Happy coding!

Comment: Hi Timothy, thanks for your answer but unfortunately still not working... nothing shows up... I tried with fruits only and still... none of the elements inside the tagname("fruits") displays :-(, I can't find the way to load this info. Please somebody help me. Thank you